# Значение this в С#

Tags: c#

Не могу разобраться в сути this.
Когда метод вызывается, ему **автоматически** передается ссылка на вызывающий
объект, т.е. тот объект, для которого вызывается данный метод

```
 class SomeClass
{    
    private string name = "No name";   
    private static void WriteToLog(SomeClass aSomeObject)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Обрабатывается объект с именем " + aSomeObject.name);
    }   

    public SomeClass(string name)
    {
        //Хотим присвоить значение аргумента, полю класса
        this.name = name;
    }    

    public void DoWork()
    {
        WriteToLog(this);       
    }    

}
```

А что передается в `WriteToLog(this)` при его вызове? Ссылка на что?

т.е. при

```
SomeClass tmpObj = new SomeClass("Иван");


tmpObj.DoWork();
```

передается ссылка на объект tmpObj ?

Comment: ссылка на экземпляр класса SomeClass

Comment: вас наверно смущает, наличие статических и нестатических методов в классе? статические методы ничего не знают о экземпляре который создаёт конструктор `public SomeClass(string name)`

Comment: *передается ссылка на объект tmpObj ?* - да

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dk1507sz.aspx)

> The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class and is also used as a modifier of the first parameter of an extension method.

> Ключевое слово *this* указывает на текущий экземпляр класса. Также используется в качестве модификатора для первого параметры в [методах расширениях](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb383977.aspx).

Таким образом внутри определения класса - это ссылка на конкретный объект, для которого выполняется тот или иной метод.

```
SomeClass tmpObj = new SomeClass("Иван");
tmpObj.DoWork();
```

*this* внутри `DoWork` в данном случае указывается на `tmlObj`, так как эта функция вызывается у этого объекта.

Comment: значит такая запись тоже имеет право на жизнь: tmpObj.DoWork(this); ?

Comment: @Proshka, все зависит от того _где_ эта запись сделана. Например: внутри статических методов _this_ недоступен, поэтому строка будет ошибкой. Если у _DoWork_ нет параметров, так же будет ошибка, если тип _this_  не совпадает с типом параметра указанного в определении  _DoWork_ - опять ошибка

Answer (score 2):

Кратко о ключевом слове [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dk1507sz.aspx) из MSDN:

> Ключевое слово this ссылается на текущий экземпляр класса, а также используется в качестве модификатора первого параметра метода расширения.

Часто используется при инициализации/реинициализации полей класса из его-же методов.

Вот простой пример:

```
class Test{
    public string name;
    string alias;

    public Employee(string name, string alias)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.alias = alias;
    }
}
```

В данном примере используя `this` вы получаете доступ к текущему экземляру класса *(проще: класс обращается сам к себе)*.

Поэтому `this.name` в этом примере - это поле класса, а `name` - параметр функции.

Надеюсь я ответил на ваш вопрос. Удачи!

Comment: _проще: класс обращается сам к себе_ - мне кажется это немного запутывает :)

Comment: @Grundy ну да, не совсем точная формулировка. Но возможно кому-то сможет помочь в понимании :)

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю к остальным ответам, что this используется для создания индексаторов.

```
class CustomMatrix
   {...
    public double this[int row, int col
    {
        get
        {
          ... 
           return arrayToStoreMtxData[row,col];
        }


    }...
    }
```

Обращение:

```
Console.WriteLine("Value is " + mtxInstance[1,2]);
```

Answer (score -2):

Для того, чтобы не было необходимости в конструкторе класса использовать this, придумали использовать нижнее подчеркивание вначале имен приватных полей, тогда
_name = name;

**P.S. Спустя почти год дополню свой ответ следующим.**

Рекомендую к просмотру отличнейший курс: [Making Your C# Code More Object-oriented](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/c-sharp-code-more-object-oriented)

"Несколько лет назад на собеседовании меня спросили о принципах ООП и интервьюер
ожидал от меня услышать то, о чем написано во всех книгах по ООП: *инкапсуляция*, *абстракция*, *наследование* и *полиморфизм*. Но я ответил, что гораздо важнее понимать на чем основано или на чем зиждутся все эти принципы ООП -
это две фундаментальные идеи: *указатель **this*** и ***Dynamic Dispatch***."

**Understanding this Pointer**

-*Silently passed with a call to an instance-level function*

Function then operate on an object

Каждая функции несет в себе ссылку на объект, в котором она оперирует

-*Bringing operations close to data*

No more global functions

Таким образом ООП в отличие от структурного программирования уходит от глобальных функций

Operations have become the quality of data structures

Данные и соответсвующие им действия следуют вместе друг с другом

**Understanding Dynamic Dispatch**

-*Object's duty*

To carry data about its type

Каждый объект несет в себе метаданные о своем типе

-*Type's duty*

To keep track of its virtual functions table

Каждый тип несет в себе таблицу виртуальных функций

To override some functions from its base type

-*Runtime's duty*

Среда выполнения динамически определяет какую функцию следует вызывать

Jump in when call is placed on an object

Find V-table of its generating type

Find concrete function address

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Я не стал как все предыдущие объяснять назначение this, а решил обратить внимание вопрошающего на другую сторону проблемы его примера, что правильное наименование переменных помогает в таких случаях. И что же вам так не понравилось в моем ответе, что вы даже заминусовали его? Давайте, не стесняйтесь, отвечайте.

Comment: Минус – не мой, но рискну предположить, что причина – несостоятельность теории ввода нижнего подчеркивания для возможности избежать использования this, а также слабым отношением самого ответа к вопросу.

Comment: @Bulson не я минусовал, но нотации есть разные.В том числе из рекомендуемых к C# нет приватных полей с помощью name. А если поле не приватное? Подобная вещь не решает проблему, т.к this чуточку мощнее, чем просто обращение к полям(можно посмотреть на многие ответы на текущий вопрос.) Вам поставили минус, т.к вы не ответили на вопрос вообще. Вопрос был в сути this, а вы предложили обход this. Раз такая мысль зашла, стоило это написать в комментарии. Теперь, возможно, ваш ответ будет вводить заблуждение и во избежание этого ответу поставили минусы, чтобы не вводить в заблуждение других.

Comment: @Arantler в ответ на ваш комментарий, я решил кое-что добавить в свой ответ.

Comment: @Bulson ахах, я не заметил число). Но больше спасибо за дополнение, прочитаю. Правда ответ так и не был дан). А вопрос: А что передается в WriteToLog(this) при его вызове? Ссылка на что? Тобишь ваше обновление помогает ответить на вопрос, но не отвечает(является даже скорее философский объяснением this)